# Using vosao with Android

Tags: java, android, vosao

I am in a bit of a pickle, I need to use vosao with an Android application but I have no idea how to authenticate and use it, I have got the JSON-RPC part working by telling me if the username and password is correct but I don't know what to do from here

Vosao is a CMS for Google App Engine.

Comment: Are you trying to access some data published with vosao on GAE? Or you want to administre your CMS with android?

Comment: Admin to cms, i want to log in and then get something like a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get round this I used JSON to parse the response from the web server, then with the same HttpClient I did all my other requests :)

Comment: Vosao uses json-rpc from the Jabsorb Library (http://code.google.com/p/jabsorb/). Vosao's authentication call is implemented by Vosao.jsonrpc.loginFrontService, see example: http://code.google.com/p/vosao/source/search?q=password&origq=password&btnG=Search+Trunk

Comment: Yeah, I just thought I would leave it there for future generations ;-)

Comment: Pretty much. This was when I couldn't work out the cookies. I figured out how to actually log in, it was just keeping that authentication